# PyTorch resnet bad tensor dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, face-recognition, face-detection, resnet

I'm trying to setup a face detection/recognition pipeline using Pytorch.

I load the image using opencv

```py
image = cv2.imread('...')
```

I load the `mtcnn` face detection and `resnet` face recognition models

```py
self.mtcnn = MTCNN(keep_all=True, device=self.device)
self.resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()
```

Then I run detection and recognition

```py
cropped = detector.mtcnn(image)
detector.resnet(cropped.unsqueeze(0))
```

And get this error

```
Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 3, 3], but got 5-dimensional input of size [1, 1, 3, 160, 160] instead
```

I also tried resizing the image to 512x512 and passing `image_size=512` to the MTCNN constructor but I get a similar error.

Comment: Please provide the full error trace.

Comment: Have you tried not unsqueezing? It's possible that the image provided to detector.mtcnn is already unsqueezed. It would make sense that you're providing a 5d tensor rather than the 4d [B, H, W, F] tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried removing the `unsqueeze` and it worked
The guide I was following was using something other than opencv to load the image which probably returned the image as an array/tensor of images